# Creating folder automatically for images in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning, subdirectory

I want to know how to create folders and store images automatically based on labels. following example code makes my question clear. i was following this tutorial https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/07/09/face-clustering-with-python/

```
from imutils import paths
import face_recognition
import argparse
import pickle
import cv2
import os
import shutil

to_load = "encodings.pickle"
data = pickle.loads(open(to_load, "rb").read())
data = np.array(data)
encodings = [d["encoding"] for d in data]
clt = DBSCAN(metric="euclidean", n_jobs=-1)
clt.fit(encodings)

labelIDs = np.unique(clt.labels_)
numUniqueFaces = len(np.where(labelIDs > -1)[0])

for labelID in labelIDs:
    mainPath = format(labelID)
    idxs = np.where(clt.labels_ == labelID)[0]
    for i in idxs:
       image = cv2.imread(data[i]["imagepath"])   # <----- This image array is what i want 
                                                  #         to store in each folder named by 
                                                  #         labelID
```

labelID output:

below labels are the different images of labels. say like -1 is image of elephant, 0 is image of lion, 1 is image of tiger. so, my question is how to create folders namely with these labeID and how to store corresponding images in it ?

```
   -1
   -1
   -1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
```

i know to create folders using os.mkdir and cv2.imwrite, but want to create specific folders from labelID for specific images.

following is the example to create folders of labelID:

```
path = format(labelID)
if os.path.exists(mainPath):
    shutil.rmtree(mainPath)
os.mkdir(mainPath)
```

it deletes folders and again make directory to avoid "folder already exists" error.
now i want to store images of those labelID in these folders.

I hope my questions are clear.
sorry for any inconvenience,
any response related to my question will be apreciated Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is

```
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(mainPath,filename),image)
```

Just an info for you, for creation of the path. There is (for python 3 at least) a flag `exist_ok` to `os.makedirs()`. It defaults to `False`, but if you set it to `True`, it will create the directory unless it already exists, in which case it will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. let me check.

Comment: Thank you it works but saves only single image to each folder :(  i even used this code to save all images:  d=0, d+=1,  filename = "file_%d.jpg" %d   <--------- this works fine without cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(mainPath, filename), image) but with this: cv2.write(filename, image)

Comment: Now it works i added True method that you mentioned ! Thank you !

Comment: Please tell me how to rename after creating those folders? Please !